# Проблема с Gulp`ом

Tags: gulp, sass, npm, scss

Тут такое...есть файл main.scss,в который импортируется файл _page-header.scss. При сохранении файла _page-header.scss происходит компиляций(ну т.к. прописано в gulpfile.js,чтобы при изменении происходила компиляция,ну не суть,это так,на всякий случай) и выдает ошибку,что нет такого файла(*page-header.scss) или не доступен для чтения,насколько я понял...но файл такой есть и галочки на "доступен только для чтения" нет...При компиляции обычных файлов все в порядке!Уже пробовал писать в файле,который импортирует в себя другие и с "*" в имени файла,и с расширением "scss",и без...Прошу,если можете,то помогите,пожалуйста...Уже пару дней ищу ответ на этот вопрос,но все в пустую...Спасибо заранее!Если что-то надо будет кинуть еще,например,сам gulpfile.js,то напишите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй `@import '_page-header';`

Comment: пробовал уже,говорил же,не помогает =(